# Imprimir datos duplicados a la derecha

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta en la que me regresa en un campo tres opciones diferentes y quiero que me devuelva esas *tres opciones* pero en *un sólo registro*.

La consulta que estoy haciendo es:

```
SELECT o.id , o.objeto , c.color FROM objeto o LEFT JOIN color c ON o.id = c.id
```

El resultado es:

[image: Resultado]

El resultado que busco es el siguiente:

> ('1','pelota','rojo','amarillo','azul')

¿Existe una forma para llegar a ese resultado?

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas? Es importante edites y agregues la etiqueta que haga referencia a lo que te menciono

Comment: por favor considera ampliar los detalles de tu pregunta en el título, queda muy ambigua, lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente usa `GROUP_CONCAT` para agrupar en solo renglón múltiples valores quedando de este modo:

```
SELECT o.id , o.objeto , GROUP_CONCAT(c.color)
FROM objeto o
LEFT JOIN color c ON o.id = c.id
GROUP BY o.id, o.objeto;
```

Finalizas agrupando por las otras dos columnas restantes

Opcionalmente a dicha concatenación puedes darle un alias con:

```
AS Listado
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Aprendiz. Me funcionó. Saludos.